# Keeping Pop-ups in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started) plugin to display menu pop-ups but the problem is when a menu item is big it gets overflow from viewport.

How can I adjust the position of pop-up menu to always keep it in the viewport.
[image]

Comment: I think I have that same desktop background..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've helped someone turn [superfish into a megadropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931879/superfish-dropdowns-to-be-columned-when-theres-many-children-and-no-grandchildr/2932775#2932775) and I think this may be a nice clean way to reformat your code with only HTML & CSS changes. Otherwise, I think you'd have to resort javascript/jQuery.